# Javascript to Python to serial

Tags: serial-port, arduino

I need a solution to my problem. I'm building a arduino robot which I plan to connect to Openwrt router. The plan is to control the robot over browser. I have running python and pyserial on my router and a webserver. The first option is to use php to serial(i have done it before turning leds on and off) the problem with that solution is that I cant just hold the button/key so the motor is turning I can only press the button and order the motors to turn some distance then again but no continuous motion. Hope you understand what I mean, if Im wrong please correct me.

So the other plan is to use Javascript to detect when the key is pressed with the keydown event something like this

```
    function checkKey(e) {
switch (e.keyCode) {
case 40:
    //alert('down');
    $('#cube').animate({
        top: "+=20px"
    })
    break;
case 38:
    //alert('up');
    $('#cube').animate({
        top: "-=20px"
    })
    break;
case 37:
    //alert('left');
    $('#cube').animate({
        left: "-=20px"
    })
    break;
case 39:
    //alert('right');
    $('#cube').animate({
        left: "+=20px"
    })
    break;
default:
    alert('???');
}
}

$(document).on("keyup", function() {
$("#cube").stop(true);
});

 if ($.browser.mozilla) {
    $(document).keydown(checkKey);
} else {
$(document).keydown(checkKey);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LjGRe/ but the problem here is that I dont know how to send the variable from javascript to python.

Please if there is a solution to my problem point me to it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

javascript is client-side, phyton is server side, so you need to send a form every time you want to communicate the data. As you can see that is really slow, as an http call have to be made for every request. Infact http protocol is not good fore real time purpoise.

You can write custom server/client protocol over TCP or UDP, as those protocol give almost-real time response, because with TCP you start a connection and keep alive it, and UDP is connection-less. Then, you can use socket in http page (it is what ajax do) but it reque a lot of skill to keep it smooth and functional.